# g++ -I and -L commands to find .hpp files not working

Tags: c++, macos, compiler-errors, compilation, g++

So I am trying to compile a file (main.cpp) that has

`#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>`

My main.cpp file is in the directory:
`~/"Documents/16_Games/01 Tetris/main.cpp"`

The Graphics.hpp file is in the directory:
`/Users/linsu/Documents/libcpp/SFML-2.5.1-macos-clang/include/SFML`

The error I am receiving is:

```
/Users/linsu/Documents/16_Games/01 Tetris/main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'SFML/Graphics.hpp' file not found
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Some commands I've tried include:

```
g++ -I /Users/linsu/Documents/libcpp/SFML-2.5.1-macos-clang/include/SFML ~/"Documents/16_Games/01 Tetris/main.cpp"

g++ -I/Users/linsu/Documents/libcpp/SFML-2.5.1-macos-clang/include/SFML ~/"Documents/16_Games/01 Tetris/main.cpp"

g++ -L /Users/linsu/Documents/libcpp/SFML-2.5.1-macos-clang/include/SFML ~/"Documents/16_Games/01 Tetris/main.cpp"

g++ -L/Users/linsu/Documents/libcpp/SFML-2.5.1-macos-clang/include/SFML ~/"Documents/16_Games/01 Tetris/main.cpp"

g++ -L/Users/linsu/Documents/libcpp/SFML-2.5.1-macos-clang/include/SFML -I/Users/linsu/Documents/libcpp/SFML-2.5.1-macos-clang/include/SFML ~/"Documents/16_Games/01 Tetris/main.cpp"

g++ -L /Users/linsu/Documents/libcpp/SFML-2.5.1-macos-clang/include/SFML -I /Users/linsu/Documents/libcpp/SFML-2.5.1-macos-clang/include/SFML ~/"Documents/16_Games/01 Tetris/main.cpp"
```

All of them throw the same error; I feel dumb. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler will only search through the exact path you provided, not through the whole chain of subdirectories. It appends the name you provided (`SFML/Graphics.hpp`) to all the paths it can look for.

It looks in all the system header locations, in current directory (`./SFML/Graphics.hpp`) and for a concatenation of path provided with `-I` and filename provided by the programmer:

```
/Users/linsu/Documents/libcpp/SFML-2.5.1-macos-clang/include/SFML/SFML/Graphics.hpp
```

Since none of these locations contains such file, compiler fails.

---

You want:

```
g++ -I/Users/linsu/Documents/libcpp/SFML-2.5.1-macos-clang/include ~/"Documents/16_Games/01 Tetris/main.cpp"
```

Notice that `SFML` directory is not in the `-I` option, because it's provided already in your code.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! One additional question: What is the difference between -I<..> and -I <...> (one with space and one without)?

Comment: @LinsuHan TBH, I have no idea. Linking library with `-l library_name` is [not recommended by GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options). About adding include paths with `-I` or library paths with `-L` there is no such note, and even worse, [they show one example with space and the other without](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options). I *think* without space is more common (and maybe better), but for exact reasoning you should ask another question (or maybe ask at GCC mailing list).